# How to count number of increases/decreases across a row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with time series data that I need to count the number of increases/decreases across a row. For example:

```
yr      value1   value2  value3  value4  #increases #decreases
1976    1        2       1       4       ?          ?
```

`#increases` in this case would be 2 and `#decreases` would be 1. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `diff` to subtract each column from the previous column. Negative values imply a decrease, while positive values imply an increase. Then you can just count them directly.

```py
diff_df = df.diff(axis=1)
df['increases'] = (diff_df > 0).sum(axis=1)
df['decreases'] = (diff_df < 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Here `(diff_df > 0)` return true/false dataframes, so summing them is just counting the "true" values - where value is positive, aka increasing.

Comment: And if we set `axis=0` then it subtracts over rows?

Comment: that's correct (see the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)