# Python bool + bool returns value 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

When I execute this piece of code in python3

```
x= bool(input())
y= bool(input())
print(x+y)
```

and when I give input as `True   True`     or `False  False`  or `True False`, 
I am getting output as `2`.
Why is it so? I expected `1` and `0` as the output.

[image]

Comment: A note to those who voted to close this on the basis that it already had an answer: no, it didn't. The OP clearly demonstrated that they already knew `False` and `True` acted like `0` and `1`. Which is what the linked answer is about. But that's not the problem here.  _Here_ the confusion was about what `input()` returns, which the linked answer says nothing about. The linked answer is fine on its own - but it's simply irrelevant to _this_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` in Python 3 returns a string. No data conversions are performed. So the inputs you get are, literally, the strings `"True"` and/or `"False"`. Then `bool()` applied to a non-empty string returns `True`.

```py
>>> bool("True")
True
>>> bool("False")
True
>>> bool("just about anything")
True
>>> bool("") # except an empty string
False
```

That's why you always get 2 no matter what you enter. Both inputs become `True`, which equals 1 in a numeric context.

```py
>>> True == 1
True
```

While people will yell at you if you do this, `eval()` is the most convenient (although dangerous!) way to evaluate a string as if it were Python code:

```py
>>> eval("True")
True
>>> eval("False")
False
```

It's dangerous because `eval()` will evaluate *any* Python expression, so if you don't trust your input it can trick your program into doing just about anything.

Answer (score 1):

`Input` converts your input to `string` format!
`bool(str)` gives you `True` state! And then you're trying to do `True + True` so you get 2!

```py
x = bool(input()) #--> x= True
y = bool(input()) #--> y= True
print(x+y) #--> True + True = 2
```

Comment: It returns 2 even when trying with False and False. That I am confused.

Comment: @MuraliSankar It should! It's what python do! And it's so helpful! Example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214701/how-to-count-number-of-increases-decreases-across-a-row-in-a-dataframe